# Excel - Complicated Summing

Tags: excel, automation, sum

Picture of excel file:
[image]

Need help with a formula or program to help automate data collection in an excel file. Example picture in the link above. I need to sum the hours for the tasks and default under department B only. Or under any department. So if done correctly based on the picture, the sum (tasks + default) for department B should equal 90.07, department A should equal 1.83, and department C should equal 166.68.

-Thanks, Justin

Comment: the tasks and default will be that name but can appear in any order under the daprtment

Comment: What have you tried? A suggestion to try is countif() or countifs()...

Comment: changed the picture to show what i have tried with the formulas i used. i just can't figure out how to sum it for a specific department

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in D2 and fill down.

[image]